# Как при нажаии на тег "a" подтвердить ввод в поле input?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть такой html код:

```
 <input class="searcher" type="text" placeholder="Введите текст:">
 <a class="searchersubmit" href="" onclick=""><img class="searchersubmitimg" src="Тут ссылка на картинку" alt=""></a>
```

Как при нажатии на ссылку(или же правильнее будет сказать картинку) подтвердить ввод в поле инпут(или же нажать enter) ?

Comment: "подтвердить ввод в поле инпут" - ??

Comment: и что по энтеру должно произойти? )

Comment: При вводе текста и последующего нажатия enter сайт производит поиск по бд. Но я хочу создать "кнопку" возле поля input, нажатие на которое "имитировало" нажатие enter в самом поле  input. Может есть какие-нибудь предложения с другим способом, но с одинаковым эффектом ?

Comment: Окей. Что бы было понятнее - зайдет на допустим savefrom.net и там вы увидите то самое поле input, а чуть правее будет та самая заветная кнопка, хоть она и имеет на данном сайте тег button.

Comment: Мне кажется, что код в вопросе не полный. Данный код не будет отправлять запрос на поиск...

Comment: "последующего нажатия enter сайт производит поиск по бд." То есть энтер вызывает какую-то функцию, передает в неё value из инпута (или сама функция берет из элемента данные), и производит поиск. Ну так и вешайте этот функционал на onclick в ссылке. Или через addeventlistener.